# Issue connecting to Kafka container from other container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

the title sums it up pretty much. I'm having issues connecting to my Kafka container from my microservice container. Everything runs nice and smoothly when I run the application locally, but when I start it using `docker-compose up -d` that is when the issues arise. So far I've tried creating a docker network, thinking that doing so would enable to containers to communicate with one another. Secondly, I've tried adding the Kafka bootstrap server URL to the Docker container, and that also did not work.

Like the stack trace for the microservice docker container states, there is an issue with my `bootstrap.server URLs`  setting, but I can't exactly put my finger on what the issue actually is. Looking for some guidance, or even just another set of eyes on this issue.

I'll attach the Kafka and microservice docker-compose file, application.properties file, and also the stack trace below in that order. I should also add that I tried using the IP address of the Kafka docker container.

Thanks, everyone.

**Kafka docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    networks:
      - tappedtechnologies-network

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://broker:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

**microservice docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://user-service_mysqldb_1:3306/userservice_db
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
    env_file:
      - src/main/resources/application-dev.properties
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=userservice_db
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

**application-dev.properties**

```
# Kafka Properties
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=broker:9092
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=PLAINTEXT
spring.kafka.topic.users.saved=tappedtechnologies.users.saved
spring.kafka.topic.users.deleted=tappedtechnologies.users.deleted

# Kafka Consumer Properties
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=userId
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer

# Kafka Producer Properties
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=saved:com.tappedtechnologies.userservice.events.UserSavedEvent, deleted:com.tappedtechnologies.userservice.events.UserDeletedEvent
```

**Microservice Logs**

```
Factory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-01T03:09:20.925Z  INFO [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 1 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values: 
        bootstrap.servers = [broker:9092]
        client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
        client.id = 
        connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 2147483647
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
        sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
        sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
        ssl.keystore.key = null
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.certificates = null
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS

2023-05-01T03:09:20.967Z  WARN [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 1 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils     : Couldn't resolve server broker:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for broker
2023-05-01T03:09:20.968Z ERROR [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 1 --- [           main] o.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin  : Could not create admin

org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:553) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.create(Admin.java:144) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient.create(AdminClient.java:49) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.createAdmin(KafkaAdmin.java:321) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.initialize(KafkaAdmin.java:201) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaAdmin.java:183) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:972) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar!/:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar!/:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar!/:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at com.tappedtechnologies.userservice.UserServiceApplication.main(UserServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[app.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[app.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:89) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:505) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
        ... 23 common frames omitted

2023-05-01T03:09:21.008Z  INFO [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8088 (http) with context path '/tapped-technologies/api/v0.1-dev'
2023-05-01T03:09:21.031Z  INFO [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 1 --- [           main] c.t.userservice.UserServiceApplication   : Started UserServiceApplication in 4.371 seconds (process running for 5.517)
```

Comment: By the way, your `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` is incorrect. You shouldn't put `broker` twice... You've copied this file, right, and changed that? It was probably correct before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DNS resolution failed for broker

Put all your services in **one** Docker compose file so that service name DNS will work. Otherwise, you must manually create a new Docker network and attach services to it.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/